# Invalid conversion from int* to int error

Tags: c

I'm getting an error in this code - `invalid conversion from int* to int` how can i correct this?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 

void walk(int,int,int,int,int,int,int);

int main() 
{ 
    int n,i; 
    scanf("%d",&n); 
    int a[10],b[10],c[30];
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
    { 
        scanf("%d",&a[i]); b[i]=0; 
    } 
    int j=1; 
    walk(1,j,0,b,c,n,a); 
    for(i=1;i<=j;i++) 
    { 
        if(c[i]==0) 
            printf("%d"); 
        else printf("%d",c[i]);
    } 
    getch(); 
} 

void walk(int i,int j,int s,int b[],int c[],int n,int a[]) 
{
    c[j]=a[i];
     j++;
    if(b[a[i]]!=1) 
    {
        b[a[i]]=1;
        walk(a[i],j,s,b,c,n,a);
    } else { 
        c[j]=0;
        s++;
        i=1;
        while(b[i]==1&&i<=n) 
            i++; 
        if(i<=n) 
            walk(i,j,s,b,c,n,a); 
        else printf("%d",s);
    }
}
```

Comment: You must be joking.

Comment: Fix your formatting.  That's entirely unreadable.

Comment: Not only that you didn't put any effort into solving the compiler error, you didn't even make any extra effort to describe the problem nor format the question properly.

Comment: Looks like perl!   OK, that was a bit much...   Will look at it anyway..

Comment: You're declaring walk as `void walk(int,int,int,int,int,int,int)` but in the definition you're using some `int[]` arguments.

Comment: @mnunberg: I know it's a bit embarrassing to actually answer a question this poor, but all the same, you should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You're declaring walk as `void walk(int,int,int,int,int,int,int)` but in the definition you're using some `int[]` arguments.

Comment: Many furry felines and canines were harmed in the writing of that code

Comment: I know about god classes, but I think we may be witnessing a *god function* here, which takes the entire state of the universe as parameters.